# Change all blank ("") keys in object to null

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Say I have an object with nested keys:

```js
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  id       : 5566,
  nicknames: ["Johnny", "Jonathan"],
  birthDate: "", // blank string. 
};
```

How do I programmatically change object keys so all values that are blank ("") change to `null`? Like this:

```js
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  id       : 5566,
  nicknames: ["Johnny", "Jonathan"],
  birthDate: null, // null instead of blank string. 
};
```

I would prefer a solution without external modules/NPM packages.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Hello, does anyone know what is wrong with my question? I’m not sure  what the problem is and why it was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through each property and check whether the value is a blank string, and if so, set it to `null`:

```js
const person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  id       : 5566,
  nicknames: ["Johnny", "Jonathan"],
  birthDate: "", // blank string. 
};

Object.keys(person).forEach(e => person[e] = person[e] == "" ? null : person[e])

console.log(person)
```